# sudo gem install cocoapods ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.?

Tags: flutter

Mac big sur ，flutter docker -v

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 12.0.1, Build version 12A7300
✗ CocoaPods not installed.
CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install:
sudo gem install cocoapods

```sh
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200927-68237-n9jbyc.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --enable-system-libffi
    --disable-system-libffi
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in `block in try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in `try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:672:in `try_ldflags'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1832:in `pkg_config'
    from extconf.rb:9:in `system_libffi_usable?'
    from extconf.rb:42:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/ffi-1.13.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/ffi-1.13.1/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue in Catalina. I solved by installing the latest version of ruby (2.7.2).

First install the Ruby Version Manager rvm:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Then install the latest version of ruby:

```
rvm install ruby-2.7.2
```

Finally try again to install the cocoapods:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/653#issuecomment-458895497

Try to switch ruby to homebrew version.

brew install ruby
brew link --overwrite ruby

If you need to have ruby first in your PATH run:
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find ruby you may need to set:
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"

For pkg-config to find ruby you may need to set:
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while installing latest `cocoapods` with `Catalina`. I updated my `MAC` to `Big Sur` and also update `Xcode`. That should work.

Comment: This is really not needed. Upgrading Os for cocoapods?

Comment: I've same issue with big sur, so this is not a good idea...